# Mockito fails in Maven but succeeds in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mockito, surefire

We have a test wich fails when executed in Maven, but succeeds in Eclipse.

Basically the problem is, that when executed with Maven Mockito fails to mock a method which comes from a superclass from another maven module with package private modifier.

**Questions**

1. Why is this so?
2. Is this a known bug? If not where to file it? surefire, mockito ...?
3. how to fix it?

I have found a [description of a similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/XVAPOG6l5gk), with the recommended fix to use surefire-2.7.1 instead of 2.7.0 but we are already on 2.10 (and also see the problem in 2.16)

Obviously the simplest solution would be to make the BaseClass public, but we can't do it, since it is not under our control.

Another alternative would be to overwrite close in MockedClass, which would be ugly but possible.

The error message is

```
failsCallingOriginalMethod(ModifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.156 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: must not have called me
```

**Relevant Code**

The real code is not in the default package, but all code is in the same package; import statements removed for brevity.

*Maven Module 1*

```
public class ModifierTest
{
    @Test
    public void failsCallingOriginalMethod()
    {
        MockedClass mock = Mockito.mock(MockedClass.class);
        doNothing().when(mock).close();
    }
}
```

*Maven Module 2*

```
public class MockedClass extends BaseClass
{
}

class BaseClass
{
    public void close()
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("must not have called me");
    }
}
```

**Versions of stuff involved**

Maven Version 3.0.5 (can't change that due to other bugs)

Oracle JDK 1.6.0_20 (reproducable with IBM JDK 1.5)

Mockito 1.95

surefire plugin 2.10 (reproducable with 2.16)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over `MockedClass`?

If so, you could consider adding a delegating method in MockedClass:

```
public void close() {
    super.close();
}
```

This doesn't solve the issue, but it's a quick workaround.